# How to not to submit form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, contact-form-7

I have a question regarding this code i was trying on my website. i wanted to minimize the size of the writing so i tried with hiding object due a simple click. But that did always submit my form.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("table").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("table").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<table style="border:solid #FFFFFF 2px;
background-color:#0000ff;height:1px;width:300px;
text-align:left;" "empty-cells:hide;" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Extras</th>
        <th>Extras</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>

[submit class:button id:form-submit "Send"]
```

Comment: There's no `<form>` element in your HTML that could be submit...?

Comment: Your code runs fine in a fiddle. Did clicking the hide/show buttons submit your form?

Comment: Hi ! yes clicking the hide show button did submit my form.
also used now an acceptance box to add a condition, so that it doesnt send it right ahead

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help and sry for the late response. i found another and easier way.
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display='none'}">+</button>
<div id="Funktionen" style="display:none;">   HERE COMES IN WHATEVER YOU WANT TO HIDE WITH the + Button </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That worked much easier withouth any further problems

> ```
> > <button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button"
> > onclick="if(document.getElementById('Funktionen')
> > .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('Funktionen')
> > .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('Funktionen')
> > .style.display='none'}">+</button> <div id="Funktionen"
> > style="display:none;">   HERE COMES IN WHATEVER YOU WANT TO HIDE WITH
> > the + Button </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the .preventDefault() function for the event. This blocks the sending when you click on a button. Notice that you need to send the event in a parameter (e).

An example:

```
$("#hide").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("table").hide();
});
```

Comment: If any of the suggestions work for you, please mark them and you questions as answered :)

Comment: Salut Francois, thanks for your help and sry for the late response. i found another and easier way.
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display='none'}">+</button>
<div id="Funktionen" style="display:none;">   HERE COMES IN WHATEVER YOU WANT TO HIDE WITH the + Button </div>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a shorten script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#switch").click(function(){
        $("table").toggle();
        $("#switch").text(($("#switch").text() == "Hide") ? "Show" : "Hide");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="border:solid #FFFFFF 2px;
background-color:#0000ff;height:1px;width:300px;
text-align:left;" "empty-cells:hide;" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Extras</th>
        <th>Extras</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>

<button id="switch">Hide</button>
```

Comment: Hi banzay, thanks for your help and sry for the late response. i found another and easier way.
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display='none'}">+</button>
<div id="Funktionen" style="display:none;">   HERE COMES IN WHATEVER YOU WANT TO HIDE WITH the + Button </div>

Comment: You found a great solution. Anyway my answer was strictly dedicated to your question subject. You asked for solution to minimize  the size of the writing with jquery and you've got what you asked. Second note of mine is my solution keeps better code readability and understanding. Despite it your solution doesn't requre jquery linking and this is also good.

Answer (score 0):

Add `type="button"` in the buttons

```
<button type="button" id="hide">Hide</button>
<button type="button" id="show">Show</button>
```

Comment: Hi Parves, thanks for your help and sry for the late response. i found another and easier way.
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display='none'}">+</button>
<div id="Funktionen" style="display:none;">   HERE COMES IN WHATEVER YOU WANT TO HIDE WITH the + Button </div>

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no  element here and for now show and hide works fine. But may be when you use this with some form then the problem would be occurring. To solve that problem use and of the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("table").hide();
        return false;
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("table").show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

--or--

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("table").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("table").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Manish ji, thanks for your help and sry for the late response. i found another and easier way.
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('Funktionen') .style.display='none'}">+</button>
<div id="Funktionen" style="display:none;">   HERE COMES IN WHATEVER YOU WANT TO HIDE WITH the + Button </div>

Comment: No problem at all :-)
if you have found my answer helpful, please upvote.